# htaccess directory restriction

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-403

I have a private folder that contains all of the private scripts and resources that I use for my website. I'm using .htaccess in the private folder to

```
    deny from all
```

which works successfully, giving a 403. However, index.php uses javascripts and css from the private folder which means it's also getting restricted. How do I fix this?

Comment: Maybe it's best to separate private and public code into different directories.

Comment: Note that you need to give access to Javascript, images, CSS, etc. to your visitors...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move the JavaScript and CSS files to a public directory so that users can download them so that they can view the web page correctly. If you want, you can disable *browsing* of the public directory by adding a `.htaccess` file in that directory with the following content:

```
Options -Indexes
```